# Cold startup, how can I "emulate" the AlwaysOn function on a free GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Let's start from the point I'm on a free GAE account because I don't need for a business account for a small CMS (VOSAO project).
I don't have particularly requests except for one: I need my app always on, I tried to mess with warmup requests (maybe I'm a newbie but I don't succeded on configuring it properly) but I haven't concluded anything.
So my question is: is there a way to "emulate" the AlwaysOn function? How can I do this?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: So you "need" a resident instance, but not enough to actually pay for it? Why?

Comment: Vosao's cold starts are not that bad actually. GAE is improving a bit over time too.

Answer (score 0):

Write a CRON script that periodically makes a request of your application to keep it always on.

Comment: Ok, I noticed Google reports that application is beel killed after "few minutes". How much are "few minutes". It has sense making a GET request for a page every n minutes, right?

Comment: Ya, so if you want to keep it active for 8 hours (working day), you could just have the CRON job make a light GET request every 2 minutes, making it a total of 240 requests.